# Solving $2^x = \sqrt{3^x}+1$ using logarithm.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I have problem solving the equation
$$2^x = \sqrt{3^x} +1$$
for $x$ using logarithm. I know the only answer is $2$ which can be proven using graphs or derivatives,etc or by dividing the two sides by $2^x$ which gives the sum of $\sin 60°$ to the power of $x$ and $\cos 60°$ to the power of $x$ equal to $1$, concluding $x=2$.

I'm looking for a way to solve it using logarithm which is not easy because of the "$1$" in one side of the equation.

Comment: Why do you expect logarithms will actually help here?  As you say, "*because of the '1' in one side of the equation*" logarithms don't actually make any sense to use.  Do not make the mistake of assuming that just because a question is easy to write that it is easy to answer.  Do not make the mistake of assuming that every equation has an elementary solution.  The general solution to $a^x = b^x + c$ is very likely going to be non-elementary, maybe involving non-elementary things like the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) if such a solution is even named.

Comment: The best you may hope to be able to do for the general case is to use numerical methods such as [Newton's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) to get better and better approximations to the solution.

Comment: See answers in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3810472/find-all-x-in-mathbbr-such-that-left-sqrt2-sqrt2-rightx-left#comment7855267_3810472.  I think all answers there can be modified to answer your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my approach.We will solve the equation for $x>0$. The case $x \leq 0$  obviously gives us no solution because:
$$ 2^{-x}=\frac{1}{2^x} \leq 1  < 1 + 3^{-\frac{x}{2}}. $$

Then for the case $x > 0$. We define:
$$f(x):= 2^x - 3^{\frac{x}{2}} - 1, ~x \in \mathbb{R}$$
Hence: $$\frac{df}{dx} = \ln 2 \cdot 2^x - \frac{\ln 3}{2}\cdot 3^{\frac{x}{2}}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot \left(\ln 4 \cdot 2^x - \ln 3\cdot \sqrt{3}^{~x} \right)>0, \forall x >  0$$
Hence $f(x)$ is increasing for all $x>0$  and therefore $f(x)$ meet x-axis at only one point and that is where $f(x)=0$. Easily find that $x=2$ satisfy $f(x)=0$ and that is our only solution.